# Connecting React Native with Meteorjs

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-native, websocket, ddp

I'm build a simple app with React Native and MeteorJs.

To establish a connection between the two frameworks i'm using DDP through the 'react-native-meteor' package.

My problem is that on my local machine, it's working fine with

```
Meteor.connect('ws://localhost:3000/websocket');
```

I have hosted my backend (the meteor js app) on heroku.

Doing :

```
Meteor.connect('ws://https://www.myapp.herokuapp.com/websocket');
```

is not working,

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

I had simply to do this

```
Meteor.connect('ws://myapp.herokuapp.com/websocket');
```

Comment: and `wss://...` for secure connection